# Why am i getting these errors in Vb.Net?

Tags: vb.net, gecko

ive included gecko (firefox engine) web browser into my project. i want to be able to not change my original code that ive used with the default web browser. can it be possible to use my existing code with the gecko engine?

Comment: Which errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create a "genericmozilla5.browser" file in your "/App_Browsers" folder in the root of your application with the following in contents:

```
<browsers>
<browser id="GenericMozilla5" parentID="Mozilla">
<identification>
<userAgent match="Mozilla/5\.(?'minor'\d+).*[C|c]ompatible; ?(?'browser'.+); ?\+?(http://.+)\)" />
</identification>
<capabilities>
<capability name="majorversion" value="5" />
<capability name="minorversion" value="${minor}" />
<capability name="browser" value="${browser}" />
<capability name="Version" value="5.${minor}" />
<capability name="activexcontrols" value="true" />
<capability name="backgroundsounds" value="true" />
<capability name="cookies" value="true" />
<capability name="css1" value="true" />
<capability name="css2" value="true" />
<capability name="ecmascriptversion" value="1.2" />
<capability name="frames" value="true" />
<capability name="javaapplets" value="true" />
<capability name="javascript" value="true" />
<capability name="jscriptversion" value="5.0" />
<capability name="supportsCallback" value="true" />
<capability name="supportsFileUpload" value="true" />
<capability name="supportsMultilineTextBoxDisplay" value="true" />
<capability name="supportsMaintainScrollPositionOnPostback" value="true" />
<capability name="supportsVCard" value="true" />
<capability name="supportsXmlHttp" value="true" />
<capability name="tables" value="true" />
<capability name="vbscript" value="true" />
<capability name="w3cdomversion" value="1.0" />
<capability name="xml" value="true" />
<capability name="tagwriter" value="System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter" />
</capabilities>
</browser>
</browsers>
```

Comment: also what if i have a profile of firefox, would that work with this code.